# Evaluate $\int_{\gamma}zRe(z)dz$

Tags: complex-analysis

I am having problem solving this:

Evaluate

$$\int_{\gamma}zRe(z)dz$$

if
$$\gamma(t)=t−it^2$$

for
$$0≤t≤2$$

I tried expanding z and $Re(z)$ into its x and y components:
$$z=x+iy$$
$$Re(z)=x$$
and 
$$dz=dx+idy$$
But I couldn't proceed further

Comment: What did you try ?

Comment: I tried expanding z into its x and y components and integrating but couldn't proceed further

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember the way to compute this kind of integral : $$\int_{\gamma} f(z) dz = \int_a^b f(\gamma(t)) \gamma'(t) dt,$$ where $\gamma$ is a parametrization on $[a,b]$. Here, your function is $z\Re(z)$ and $\gamma(t) = t-it^2.$ Hence $$\int_{\gamma} z\Re(z)dz =\int_0^2 (t-it^2)t(1-2it)dt.$$ Can you proceed further ?

Comment: Oh, thanks I can proceed from here. So it means you parameterise $z$ to $\gamma(t)$